# libtar segfaults on tar_append_tree

Tags: c, linux, tar

Linux machine 3.2.0-34-generic, x86_64

Source: libtar
Version: 1.2.11-8

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libtar.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(void)
{
TAR *pTar;
char *tarFilename = "file.tar";
char *srcDir = "/home/test";
char *extractTo = ".";
tar_open(&pTar, tarFilename, NULL, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644, TAR_GNU);
tar_append_tree(pTar, srcDir, extractTo);
tar_close(pTar);
return (0);
}
```

Compiling as:

gcc main.c -o run -ltar

Getting segfault

Now with "gcc main.c -g3 -O0 -o run -ltar"

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7845425 in __GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>)
at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
64  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
0  0x00007ffff7845425 in __GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>)
at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
1  0x00007ffff7848b8b in __GI_abort () at abort.c:91
2  0x00007ffff788339e in __libc_message (do_abort=2, 
  fmt=0x7ffff798ae3f "*** %s ***: %s terminated\n")
  at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:201
3  0x00007ffff7919807 in __GI___fortify_fail (
  msg=0x7ffff798add6 "buffer overflow detected") at fortify_fail.c:32
4  0x00007ffff7918700 in __GI___chk_fail () at chk_fail.c:29
5  0x00007ffff79179e6 in __strncpy_chk (s1=<optimized out>, 
  s2=<optimized out>, n=<optimized out>, s1len=<optimized out>)
  at strncpy_chk.c:34
6  0x00007ffff7bd12ef in th_finish () from /usr/lib/libtar.so.0
7  0x00007ffff7bd0dc1 in th_write () from /usr/lib/libtar.so.0
8  0x00007ffff7bd07f0 in tar_append_file () from /usr/lib/libtar.so.0
9  0x00007ffff7bd3c12 in tar_append_tree () from /usr/lib/libtar.so.0
10 0x00000000004006f1 in main () at main.c:12
```

All examples, f.e. here

[Using libtar to compress a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958597/using-libtar-to-compress-a-directory)

Seems to work fine....

Comment: Have you checked that the `tar_open` call succeeded?

Comment: The tar_open(), tar_fdopen(), and tar_close() functions return 0 on success. On failure, they return -1 and set errno.

Comment: int rc=tar_open(&pTar, tarFilename, NULL, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644, TAR_GNU);

printf("%d", rc);

file created successfully with the size of 0bytes

returns 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a library defect
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=538770

You may need to upgrade libtar-devel

Comment: Checked with ftp://ftp.feep.net/pub/software/libtar/libtar-1.2.11.tar.gz  and problem solved. Thanks a lot!